# Handbrake 1.51 stays in the system even after uninstall

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall, handbrake

I am trying to remove Handbrake completely after finding out I had two versions installed in my system. I succeeded at removing `handbrake-jz`, but the other one (version 1.51) won't uninstall.

I tried [this method](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/handbrake?type=uninstall) in vain.  I got positive results in terminal and after rechecking, I got a confirmation saying handbrake was not installed.

However, to my surprise, the icon still appears in the *Show Applications* menu.  If I click it then the app will open normally. If I do a search in the Store, the app shows up with a green "install" button. What's happening here?

Comment: But you had two versions installed at the same time? So if you remove one of them, you still have one left, and are therefore still able to open one of them. Could you please check within the application itself what version it has. Also what source(Snap, flatpak or deb) did you use to install?

Comment: Thank you, you put me in the right direction. I totally forgot I installed a couple of flatpaks before. I listed them and found handbrake in there. It's gone now, have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the #apt-get remove cmd.  The reply is 'app not found'.  I don't remember how and when it was installed.

Nice to see someone else having issue(s) with handbrake (I'm not alone in these matters).  I'd like to know how to list in the terminal the installed version of Handbrake, with something other than apt.  Apt gives me a 'warning' and the Software Center takes a long time to search for Handbrake.  I am trying to avoid having 2 versions of same app being installed.

I have just found Handbrake using the Software app in Activities and uninstalled Handbrake from there.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287709)